# How to pass data from one form to another suitescript

Tags: netsuite

Well it looks like I need to suite script this.

I want to populate a field in my child record from the form that is creating the record.

When the user clicks to add a new child record, I want to pass some info to the creation of that child record from the current parent that initialized the create child.

How is this done?

MORE INFO:

I originally looked at Sourcing and filtering, but that was dependent on the parent record being the same. Let's say I have a note record. Meanwhile I have other entities which can have a note created and linked to it.

Something like adding the set name to a note:

Set
 -->> Books --> Note (set name = books.set.name )

-->> Authors --> Note (set name= authors.set.name)

So unless I can use some eval technique, I would think I should start my dive into suite script.

Comment: I don't know how to contact you directly  @egrubaugh360. Anyway, An Author or a Book can be a parent and create a note. Now in my note I want to populate or validate some data coming from its current parent. However, the parent could be book or an author. I was thinking if I could pass the parent in suite script I could code the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround I found was to use window.opener in a client script:

```
function rulePageInit(){
var wo = window.opener.nlapiGetFieldValue ('custrecord_configurator');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can script this, but you do not necessarily have to. NetSuite's primary mechanism for doing this is ***Sourcing***.

On the definition of each custom field that you want to populate from the parent, you just need to set up the *Sourcing and Filtering* tab appropriately to pull data from the parent record. I believe you will set the *Source List* to be the field that links to the parent, and then you will set the *Source From* to be the field on the parent that you are copying data from.

If you only want the field to be sourced once at the time of creation, then you can check the *Store Value* checkbox on the field definition. This will set the field once and then divorce it from the parent record so that you can change the two fields independently.

If you want the field to dynamically pull from the parent every time you view the record, then you should uncheck *Store Value*. Be aware that unchecking this means the field will no longer be scriptable or searchable.

See the NetSuite Help page titled *Setting Sourcing Criteria* for more details about the relevant settings.

Comment: Yes. I thought about sourcing and you would be correct 80% of the time. However, the problem is that the original parent can be different.

Comment: I would need to see more detail on your set up to help more. If you want to send more detail of how you've got these records configured and the scenarios you're encountering, I can probably provide more guidance.